# php/laravel not sure what code is being called to create new instance of a model

Tags: php, laravel, constructor, model

I'm relatively new to php. In my project an instance of a model is being created like this:

```
$blah = new SomeModelName(['arg1' => $arg1, 'arg2' => $arg2, 'arg3' => $arg3]);
```

I thought that when the `new` keyword is used that calls the `__costruct` function within the model. Well, the model extends different classes all the way back to the `Model.php` located in `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent`.

I've traced back to the base `Model.php` class and in all of the child classes there is no `__construct` function that would override `__construct` from the base `Model.php` class, so I thought that the `__construct` function in the base `Model.php` class in `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent` is what should be called. But, I've put a debug statement in the base `Model.php` class and it's not outputting, so it appears that `__construct` in the base `Model.php` is not the `__construct` function being called.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to where to find the `__construct` function being called when the class is being initialized?

Comment: It makes no sense to pass arguments unless you have defined your own constructor that will use them.

Comment: @miken32 that's why i'm confused. `SomeModelName.php` does not have it's own `__construct` function and it extends `SomeOtherModel.php`, which in turn does not have a `__construct` function either. So on and so on back to the `Model.php`, and that is the only place I can find a `__construct` function. So I guess I'm asking, if I can't find a `__construct` function to override the `__construct` function from the base `Model.php` class, where else should I look to see what is happening when `new SomeModelName` is being run?

Comment: when you call `new SomeModel()` is called the `__construct()` function defined on `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` and it is not overriden anywhere. The argument is the array of attributes.

Comment: @dparoli yes, that's what I understand should happen. But, I've put a display statement in the `__construct` function in the base `Model.php` and that display statement is not showing, which leads me to believe that the `__construct` function in the base `Model.php` class is not getting called, hence my question.

Comment: The function won't be run if you're passing bad arguments to it. Check your logs for "TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model::__construct() must be of the type array, xxxx given"

Comment: I can assure you that is called, only Taylor Otwell in person can change my idea. You should have some other problem.

Comment: i've looked in my laravel log and there are no errors showing up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User-defined models inherit from `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` which is an abstract class that defines this method:

```
/**
 * Create a new Eloquent model instance.
 *
 * @param  array  $attributes
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
{
    $this->bootIfNotBooted();

    $this->initializeTraits();

    $this->syncOriginal();

    $this->fill($attributes);
}
```

Note that the argument is type-hinted to `array`. If you pass the function something else, a `TypeError` will occur and it will not be run.

You can create a constructor on your own model that does something with the arguments provided. For example:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Widget extends Model
{

    private $foo;
    private $bar;

    public function __construct($arg1, $arg2)
    {
        $this->foo = $arg1;
        $this->bar = $arg2;
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

$widget = new Widget($arg1, $arg2);
```

But it's more typical to use setters or pass the attributes directly:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Widget extends Model
{

    private $foo;
    private $bar;

}

$attributes = ["foo"=>$arg1, "bar"=>$arg2];
$widget = new Widget($attributes);
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion, i was wrong in my original post, the argument passed to the constructor actually is an array which should be fine for the constructor. i've modified my OP accordingly. but even considering that my display statement is still not showing like it should.

Comment: Ok but take a look at what the constructor does with the array. Passes it on to `fill()` which populates the model, mapping properties to array keys, which you don't have. Try an associative array as in my example.

Comment: you are right again. and after I checked again it is an associative array that is being passed into the constructor. sorry for the confusion, i have updated my OP again to reflect this.

Comment: Try to comment out this line `$this->fill($attributes);` in the Eloquent/Model constructor and see if your derived class has the attributes assigned, you will see that is called.

Comment: @GharbadTheWeak or just put `dd($attributes);` as first line.

Comment: @dparoli, that's what i mean, I have `dd('some message');` as the first line within `__construct` function in the base `Model.php` class in the eloquent model which should show `some message` when `new SomeModelName();` is called but it's not showing. i'm using Postman to run an api call, and other `var_dump()` display statements are showing right before the `dd()` in `Model.php` but the message in `Model.php` isn't showing. frustrating...

Comment: I have put `dd('some message');` as the first line within `__construct` function in `Eloquent\Model` I opened the tinker REPL `php artisan tinker` and I wrote `$u = new User()` and "some message" showed up. You should have some caching enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are you trying to do. But when you look at the [`Model`](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Model.php) class, you'll see the magic method. Here is what happened in that `constructor`.

```
    public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
    {
        $this->bootIfNotBooted();
        $this->initializeTraits();
        $this->syncOriginal();
        $this->fill($attributes);
    }
```

You see there is [`$attributes`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#mass-assignment) parameter. It will help you initiate the object with mass assignment(but you have to write `$fillable` property first).

So in the case you want to create a new object, You just have to write `new Company(['name' => "Hilman Corp.", 'city' => "Mojokerto"])`. Here is the `Company` class.

```
class Company extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name','city'];

}
```

Maybe you want to add logic to your `constructor` to upper case first letter. You can easily modify your code as below.

```
class Company extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name','city'];

    public function __construct(array $attributes=[])
    {
        $attributes['city'] = ucfirst($attributes['city']);
        parent::__construct($attributes);
    }   
}
```

My advice is not to rewrite something that could break how the Laravel treats a class. It could give you pain later when upgrading the Laravel version.